# Установка уведомлений в Android в свое приложение

Tags: android-sdk, android

Как поставить уведомления Google Cloud Messaging в свое приложение Android? 2 день разбираюсь, уже запутался, на habrahabr в статьях пишут, что нужна .jar библиотека, в официальной документации Android пишут, что нужно скачать в android sdk "google play services" и заимпортить в свой проект как библиотеку. Я запутался как делать. Мне нужно сделать лишь часть на Android, на сервере сделает другой человек. 
Объясните пожалуйста, или дайте ссылку, где все рассказано, какую библиотеку использовать, что куда писать и т.д. Будет еще лучше, если кто то уделит пару минут и объяснит в icq, skype, vk и т.д. Буду очень благодарен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Либу берёте отсюда **/user/android-sdk-linux/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib**

2) Примеров в инете уйма. Например [вот](http://fundroiding.wordpress.com/2012/06/29/google-cloud-messaging-for-android-gcm-simple-tutorial/)

Согласен, даже по примерам сложно что-то сделать. Косяк может быть, если забыл один пермишен, если в манифесте что-то не дописали, если имя сервиса криво написали и т.д. надо пробовать)

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете Gradle, то достаточно написать

```
dependencies {
   // Google Play Services
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.42'
}
```

и у вас всё подключиться, если нет, то откройте SDK manager и скачайте пакет:

[image]